# How to prevent redirecting to another page while assigning a flow to custom button

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, custom-button, automation, developer-org

I had created a flow for automating my things. I created a custom button and assigned a flow to it. When I try to press the button it takes me to another page. Can someone tell how can i prevent it from going to another page?

Answer (score 0):

What type of flow is this? Use an auto-launched flow instead of a screen flow, that should not take you to another screen.